# Make a long type signature

Tags: code-challenge, busy-beaver, functional-programming

## Challenge

Find an expression, at most 100 bytes long, with the longest type signature.

## Rules

- Any statically typed language with type inference is allowed
- The type must be non-ambiguous, but otherwise may include types without defined instances. For example `Num [a]` and `Eq [a]` are allowed, even without a defined instance
- No imports other than the minimum required to compile a program with STDIN/STDOUT
- Infinite types are not allowed
- If an answer has more than one expression, only one may contribute to the score. For example, although the type signature of composition is `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, having a score of 20, the answer with 25 copies of `(.)\n` would have a score of 20, not 500
- The expression must be, at most, 100 bytes
- The score is the number of characters in the type signature, excluding the name of the function and any whitespace. For example, `f :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` would have a score of 12
- The highest score wins!

## Examples

Although other languages are allowed, the following examples are in Haskell:

```
Score: 112
map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map.map
f :: (a -> b)
 -> [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[a]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
 -> [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[b]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]    

Score: 240
(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.).(.)
f :: (b->c)->(a->a1->a2->a3->a4->a5->a6->a7->a8->a9->a10->a11->a12->a13->a14->a15->a16->a17->a18->a19->a20->a21->a22->a23->a24->b)->a1->a2->a3->a4->a5->a6->a7->a8->a9->a10->a11->a12->a13->a14->a15->a16->a17->a18->a19->a20->a21->a22->a23->a24->c

Score: 313
foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl$foldl(.)
f :: (Foldable t, Foldable t1, Foldable t2, Foldable t3, Foldable t4,
  Foldable t5, Foldable t6, Foldable t7, Foldable t8, Foldable t9,
  Foldable t10, Foldable t11, Foldable t12, Foldable t13,
  Foldable t14, Foldable t15) =>
 (b -> c)
 -> t (t1 (t2 (t3 (t4 (t5 (t6 (t7 (t8 (t9 (t10 (t11 (t12 (t13 (t14 (t15 (b
 -> b))))))))))))))))
 -> b
 -> c

Score: 538
lex.show.foldl1.mapM.traverse.sum.mapM.sum.traverse.(.).mapM.scanl.zipWith3((.traverse).(.traverse))
 (Num
    (a -> ([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]]) -> [[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]]),
  Num
    (([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]])
     -> t1 (t2 ([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]]))
     -> [[c]]
     -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]]),
  Show
    (t (t1 (t2 ([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]])))
     -> t1 (t2 ([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]]))),
  Applicative f, Foldable t,
  Foldable ((->) (t1 (t2 ([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]])) -> a)),
  Foldable
    ((->) (([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]]) -> a -> t3 [a1 -> f b])),
  Traversable t1, Traversable t2, Traversable t3, Traversable t4,
  Traversable t5,
  Traversable ((->) (t1 (t2 ([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]])))),
  Traversable ((->) ([[c]] -> t3 [[a1 -> f b]]))) =>
 [(t5 (t4 a1) -> f (t5 (t4 b))) -> c -> a1 -> f b]
 -> [(String, String)]
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69189/194). I did think there was an almost exact dupe, but I haven't found it.

Comment: I suspect that a language with dependent typing can make a type signature of the length of any number of can compute.

Comment: @xnor As type systems themselves may be turing complete (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4047732/5154287), I guess it becomes more of a busy beaver problem then. Should I edit the tags?

Answer (score 19):

### Haskell, ~2^(2^18)

```haskell
f x=(x,x)
g=f.f.f.f
h=g.g.g.g
i=h.h.h.h
j=i.i.i.i
k=j.j.j.j
l=k.k.k.k
m=l.l.l.l
n=m.m.m.m
n.n.n.n$0
```

Each application of `f` roughly double the type signature by transforming the type signature `T` to `(T,T)`. For example, the fourfold composition `f.f.f.f$0` has type

```
Num a => ((((a, a), (a, a)), ((a, a), (a, a))), (((a, a), (a, a)), ((a, a), (a, a))))
```

Each line quadraples the number of applications of `f`, giving `4^9 = 2^18` at the end. So, the type signature has size of the order of `2^(2^18)`.

Comment: The classic approach, but I think the parameters can be better tuned. Specifically, I think that `f x=(x,x,x)` at the cost of one `n.` in the last line gives the optimal score for this overall structure.

Comment: I don't know Haskell, so I could be off base here, but I'll point out that 4^(4^4) is less than 3^(4^5)

Comment: Pretty sure the 4th `n.` is going to be larger. `2^18` vs `3 * (2^16)` unless I made a mistake calculating the original exponentiation: `2^(4^9)` vs. `3^((4^8)*3)`

Comment: No, @PeterTaylor is correct: 2^(4^9) = 16^(4^8) < 27^(4^8) = 3^(4^8 ⋅ 3).

Comment: `(,)` (or `(,,)`) can be used to save some bytes and improve the score by using more `n`s.

Comment: @BWO I don’t see how: since `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)` has two type variables repeated twice rather than one type variable repeated thrice, the type of `(,).(,).(,).(,) :: a -> b1 -> (b2 -> (b3 -> (b4 -> (a, b4), b3), b2), b1)` only grows as \$O(n \log_{10} n)\$ with the number of `(,)`s instead of exponentially. You can write xnor’s `f` as `id=<<(,)` but that’s longer. You can use `(:)`, leading to the [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170171/39242) I posted the day before your comment.

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) with extensions, \$\ggg A(A(A(A(220,0),0),0),0)\$

```hs
Z::Z#Z#Z#Z#Z#Z#Z#Z#Z?Z
data a?b=Z|S(a?b)
type family m#n where Z#n=S n;S m#Z=m#S m;S m#S n=m#(S m#n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1Ba8MwDIXv@RUCXxJo/kCH6WFjMHpYICsDs4uaqK6ZrYbIpQvb/vo8db0NHd73nsTTEeWdYiyfrYGI7M/oCbpTXLaBR1k9YMYbvSwTPWIKMdDNPE80Yz7NstrxSEMYcR/piSUjD3py33Vg2u/qw8Jbceu1M/9m46pR2wE3e@u@@lq1qbIWw@H6ZoFkGC5HmgmcYdsD3/WaOZuM6h9rpq6@IjclYWA7nWeqm/IzHCJ6Ke1rCiKBfSvBM2bdyi8)

Requires `-XDataKinds`, `-XPolyKinds`, `-XTypeOperators`, `-XUndecidableInstances`, and `-XTypeFamilies`.

Many thanks to Ørjan Johansen, who realized that making the natural number constructor infix and building the arguments a bit differently saved two bytes, making just enough room for another iteration of `#`.

Obviously, the type checker will give up trying to check this program. To get a general sense of what the signature would look like (if it were small enough to fit in the observable universe), try the much smaller

```hs
Z::S(S Z)#Z?Z
```

### Explanation

The `#` type family is closely related the [Ackermann–Péter function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), commonly written \$A\$, but `#` grows faster. The Ackermann–Péter function is defined

> \$A(0,n)=n+1\$
>
> \$A(m,0)=A(m-1,1)\$ when \$m > 0\$
>
> \$A(m,n)=A(m-1, A(m, n-1))\$ when \$ m, n > 0 \$

`#`, on the other hand, we can call \$B\$, and write

> \$B(0,n)=n+1\$
>
> \$B(m,0)=B(m-1,m)\$ when \$m > 0\$
>
> \$B(m,n)=B(m-1, B(m, n-1))\$ when \$m,n > 0\$

Only the second case is different. The termination proof is identical to the standard one for \$A\$, and it should be clear that \$B(m,n) \ge A(m,n)\$ for all \$m\$ and \$n\$.

Here we calculate a unary representation of

> \$r = B(B(B(B(B(B(B(B(0,0),0),0),0),0),0),0),0) \$

By direct calculation, \$B(B(B(B(0,0),0),0),0)=220\$, so

> \$r = B(B(B(B(220,0),0),0),0)\$.

Note that \$A(A(A(A(0,0),0),0),0)\$ is only \$5\$, so we've bumped things up a good bit to start out. I don't have a very clear sense of just how much faster \$B\$ grows than \$A\$, but considering how the calculation proceeds, it seems likely to grow quite a lot faster.

The number of digits in even \$A(6,0)\$ is too large to express practically in decimal, so this is ... rather ridiculously large.

The definition of the natural numbers, `(?)`, is a bit non-standard. To save space, we use `(?)` as both a natural number type (at the type level) and a proxy type (at the term level).

I believe that either `TypeFamilies` or (more verbosely and obfuscatedly) `FunctionalDependencies` are necessary to get the type-level computation required to reach truly large types. `UndecidableInstances` is needed to work around Haskell's very primitive termination checking. The other extensions are only needed to compress the code into the small available space.

Comment: [One more `#Z`](https://tio.run/##XY1Ba8MwDIXv@RUCXxJo/kCL6WFjMHpYIC0F04uaqI6ZrYbIpQ1b//o8d70NHfS9J/HegPJJ3qevWoFHthe0BM3ZzxvHvSxeMeKTtvNIbxicd/QUHyNNGM@TLHbcU@d6PHp6Z4nIXX55aRpQ9b24aTgks1wa9W/WpuhzOuD6qM13W@ZdFTEHw@lRM0NQDNeBJgKjWLfAqzZ7RgfVgvnj7GVVPpCrFNCxHi8TlVX66U4eraR6H5yIY1uLs4wxX@UX "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, is stacking up `Z`s at the front better than starting with `S(S Z)#S Z`, or the same?

Comment: Either way, the extra `#Z` at the end is most welcome.

Comment: It's the exact same value but saves one byte, and changing the datatype to `?` saves the other, leaving room for the extra `#Z`.

Comment: While you were first editing, I discovered `A(m,1)` was never bigger than `A(A(m,0),0)`, and was about to remark on it, but then you'd just optimized to the point where the options were equal. (Also `m+1` is never bigger than `A(m,0)`.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I've made a fairly substantial improvement; I'd really appreciate if you could double check that I haven't goofed up the calculation somewhere.

Comment: Looks good, although if we're tweaking the function, I think [this](https://tio.run/##VY1Ba8MwDIXv@RUCXxJo/kCL6WFjMHpYIC0F04uaqI6ZrYbIpQ1b//o8dz0NHfTpvcfTgPJJ3qevWoFHthe0BM3ZzxvHvSxeMeKTtvNIbxicd/Q8PkaaMJ4nWey4p871ePT0zhKRuxx5aRpQ9b24aTgks1wa9W/WpuhzN@D6qM13W@ZdFTHXwunxZIagGK4DTQRGsW7LFrhatVk2OqjwR1nKXD6QqxTQsR4vE5VV@ulOHq2keh@ciGNbi7OMMbvyCw "Haskell – Try It Online") gets out of the ballpark faster - `Z#Z#Z#Z` is already humongous, which makes up for the one byte longer type family.

Comment: My intuition btw is that all of these functions are "about the same size" for each m plus or minus 1, once you get into the incomprehensibly large territory, so it's all about getting there as fast as possible and then have room to heap on more `#Z`s.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, the switch from `A` to `B` was a no-brainer, because it has the same number of bytes. As for how they compare ... my intuition isn't great. Certainly, though, getting a fast start is very helpful for obtaining results whose size is easy to bound (below) by well-known functions like `A`. Thanks for the improvement; I actually considered the `S(S n)` change alone before I realized there was free Indian buffet lunch to be had.

Answer (score 11):

## Java, score 17301488

Requires the method `<T>java.util.Map<T,T>f(T t){return null;}`, which has been counted towards the 100-byte limit.

`f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(1)))))))))))))))))))`

The compile-time type signature of this should match [this.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66Q2_YrkhNnQTJkX1ZZb3RjNU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hmm. since lambdas are allowed this would probably get a higher score

Answer (score 11):

## Haskell, 9·2<sup>663552</sup> − 3 (≈ 1.02·10<sup>199750</sup>)

A small (“small”) improvement over [xnor’s 5⋅2<sup>262144</sup> + 5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71797/make-a-long-type-signature/71800#71800).  This is 99 bytes.

```hs
f=(:).(:)
g=f.f.f.f
h=g.g.g.g
i=h.h.h.h
j=i.i.i.i
k=j.j.j.j
l=k.k.k.k
m=l.l.l
n=m.m.m
o=n.n.n
o.o.o
```

#### How it works

We have

```hs
(:)         :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(:).(:)     :: a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]
(:).(:).(:) :: a -> [[[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]] -> [[[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
```

and so on, with the length roughly doubling for each `(:)`. The given expression `o.o.o` works out to `(:).(:).(:).….(:)` with 2·4<sup>6</sup>·3<sup>4</sup> = 663552 copies of `(:)`.

## Haskell with `FlexibleContexts` and `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, (200·4<sup>331776</sup> + 75·331776 + 16)/9 ≈ 2.53·10<sup>199750</sup>

A small improvement over [Bubbler’s 12·2<sup>663552</sup> + 9·663552 − 4 ≈ 1.36·10<sup>199750</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71797/make-a-long-type-signature/178294#178294), which also relies on these extensions.  The wording of the challenge sort of suggests it might be okay to rely on them (“For example `Num [a]` and `Eq [a]` are allowed, even without a defined instance”); I’m not sure.  This is 100 bytes.

```hs
f=(/).(:)
g=f.f.f.f
h=g.g.g.g
i=h.h.h.h
j=i.i.i.i
k=j.j.j.j
l=k.k.k.k
m=l.l.l
n=m.m.m
o=n.n.n
-o.o.o
```

#### How it works

We have

```hs
-(/).(:) :: (Fractional ([a] -> [a]), Num (a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a])) => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
-(/).(:).(/).(:) :: (Fractional ([a] -> [a]), Fractional ([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]), Num (a -> ([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]])) => a -> ([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]
-(/).(:).(/).(:).(/).(:) :: (Fractional ([a] -> [a]), Fractional ([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]), Fractional ([([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]] -> [([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]]), Num (a -> ([([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]] -> [([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]]) -> [([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]] -> [([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]])) => a -> ([([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]] -> [([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]]) -> [([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]] -> [([([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]) -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]] -> [([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]]]
```

and so on, with the length roughly quadrupling for each `(/).(:)`. The given expression `-o.o.o` works out to `-(/).(:).(/).(:).….(/).(:)` with 4<sup>6</sup>·3<sup>4</sup> = 331776 copies of `(/).(:)`.

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 12·2<sup>663552</sup> + 9·663552 - 4

Yet another small improvement over [Anders Kaseorg's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170171/78410).

```
f=(/).(/)
g=f.f.f.f
h=g.g.g.g
i=h.h.h.h
j=i.i.i.i
k=j.j.j.j
l=k.k.k.k
m=l.l.l
n=m.m.m
o=n.n.n
o.o.o
```

#### How it works

```
(/) -- score 27
   :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
(/).(/) -- score 62
   :: (Fractional a, Fractional (a -> a)) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
(/).(/).(/) -- score 119
   :: (Fractional a, Fractional (a -> a), Fractional ((a -> a) -> a -> a)) =>
      a -> ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
(/).(/).(/).(/) -- score 224
   :: (Fractional a, Fractional (a -> a),
       Fractional ((a -> a) -> a -> a),
       Fractional (((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a)) =>
      a
      -> (((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a)
      -> ((a -> a) -> a -> a)
      -> (a -> a)
      -> a
      -> a
```

Just changed function composition `(.)` to fractional division `(/)`. The `Fractional x` part in the function signature explodes along with the main part, giving slightly higher constant multiplier.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 979

```
#define a int,int,int
#define b a,a,a,a
#define c b,b,b
#define d c,c,c
#define e d,d,d
int(*f)(e);
```

`f` has the signature:

```
int(*)(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)
```

Comment: 979 33554438 58640620148060 this looks like some ridiculous OEIS entry. possibly the largest changes in magnitude I've ever seen in a PPCG entry being refined.

Comment: @Sparr [you ain't seen nuthin' yet](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71829/46231)

Answer (score 5):

## Idris, >hyper(hyper(hyper(hyper(999999999, 99, 99), 99,99),99,99),99,99)

```
f:Nat->Type
f Z=()
f(S n)=hyper n n n~=~f n
the$f$hyper(hyper(hyper(hyper 999999999 9 9) 9 9)9 9)9 9
```

### Explanation:

We're defining a function f, computing a type f(0) is just the unit type, while f(S(n)) computes to the equality type applied to the function argument "hypered" by itself and to f applied to n. The last line basically is a function expecting a value of a type like (27 = (4 = (2 = (1 = ()))))) (for n=4).

## Simple Example

```
f 3 = (27 = (4 = (2 = (1 = ()))))
```

Comment: I don't *really* know Idris, but I think this may fail on a technicality: You're supposed to maximize the length of the type signature of an expression, not the length of its value. Isn't the type signature of your final expression just `:Type`?

Comment: What do you mean by an uncomputable *number*? I'm not familiar with `hyper`; could you explain?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oh yes, just fixed that and applied a few more changes

Comment: @dfeuer uncomputable only in the way such that the process would take until the end of the universe.

Comment: (0) Explanation seems lagging a bit. (1) This is just 98 bytes now. (2) Since the first argument of `hyper` gets amplified enormously more than the rest, I think you want all/most of those `99`s to be `9`s. (3) Assuming Idris's `$` works like Haskell's, the outer set of parentheses after `f$` is redundant. (4) Could you abbreviate `hyper` or would that require a type signature itself?

Comment: And what is `hyper`?

Comment: @dfeuer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation ([The Idris definition](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr) is a direct translation.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen (1,2,3) fixed, (4) would require a type signature since implicit arguments determined by the type signature are a thing in idris

Comment: Hm, for the same reason as (2), I suspect you'll get a huger type by dropping `f` and just putting something like `~=~()` at the end of the final expression.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen probably, but it wouldn't be as fun xD

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 363

Expression:

```
new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=new{a=""}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Type signature:

```
<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[<>f__AnonymousType0#1`1[System.String]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](http://csharppad.com/gist/487852bf2e208a896377)

Answer (score 2):

## Go 1.0 without `reflect`, 98

Go 1.x types are statically defined. Here is my first try:

```
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]string{}
```

[On the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MC8pTVC1K6D):

```
package main;import "fmt"
func main() {

    x := [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]string{}

    fmt.Printf("%d %T\n", len(fmt.Sprintf("%T", x)), x)
}
```

## Go 1.9 using type aliases, 2389

```
type(I=interface{f();g()};S=struct{p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z I});map[S]map[S]map[S]map[S]map[S]map[S]S{}
```

[On the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K6H6WqF04fI):

```
package main;import("fmt";"strings")
func main() {

    type(I=interface{f();g()};S=struct{p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z I});x:=map[S]map[S]map[S]map[S]map[S]map[S]S{}

    fmt.Printf("%d %T\n", len(strings.Replace(fmt.Sprintf("%T", x), " ", "", -1)), x)
}
```

Result:

```
2389 map[struct { p interface { main.f(); main.g() }; q interface { main.f(); main.g() }; r interface { main.f(); main.g() }; s interface { main.f(); main.g() }; t interface { main.f(); main.g() }; u interface { main.f(); main.g() }; v interface { main.f(); main.g() }; w interface { main.f(); main.g() }; x interface { main.f(); main.g() }; y interface { main.f(); main.g() }; z interface { main.f(); main.g() } }]map[struct { p interface { main.f(); main.g() }; q interface { main.f(); main.g() }; r interface { main.f(); main.g() }; s interface { main.f(); main.g() }; t interface { main.f(); main.g() }; u interface { main.f(); main.g() }; v interface { main.f(); main.g() }; w interface { main.f(); main.g() }; x interface { main.f(); main.g() }; y interface { main.f(); main.g() }; z interface { main.f(); main.g() } }]map[struct { p interface { main.f(); main.g() }; q interface { main.f(); main.g() }; r interface { main.f(); main.g() }; s interface { main.f(); main.g() }; t interface { main.f(); main.g() }; u interface { main.f(); main.g() }; v interface { main.f(); main.g() }; w interface { main.f(); main.g() }; x interface { main.f(); main.g() }; y interface { main.f(); main.g() }; z interface { main.f(); main.g() } }]map[struct { p interface { main.f(); main.g() }; q interface { main.f(); main.g() }; r interface { main.f(); main.g() }; s interface { main.f(); main.g() }; t interface { main.f(); main.g() }; u interface { main.f(); main.g() }; v interface { main.f(); main.g() }; w interface { main.f(); main.g() }; x interface { main.f(); main.g() }; y interface { main.f(); main.g() }; z interface { main.f(); main.g() } }]map[struct { p interface { main.f(); main.g() }; q interface { main.f(); main.g() }; r interface { main.f(); main.g() }; s interface { main.f(); main.g() }; t interface { main.f(); main.g() }; u interface { main.f(); main.g() }; v interface { main.f(); main.g() }; w interface { main.f(); main.g() }; x interface { main.f(); main.g() }; y interface { main.f(); main.g() }; z interface { main.f(); main.g() } }]map[struct { p interface { main.f(); main.g() }; q interface { main.f(); main.g() }; r interface { main.f(); main.g() }; s interface { main.f(); main.g() }; t interface { main.f(); main.g() }; u interface { main.f(); main.g() }; v interface { main.f(); main.g() }; w interface { main.f(); main.g() }; x interface { main.f(); main.g() }; y interface { main.f(); main.g() }; z interface { main.f(); main.g() } }]struct { p interface { main.f(); main.g() }; q interface { main.f(); main.g() }; r interface { main.f(); main.g() }; s interface { main.f(); main.g() }; t interface { main.f(); main.g() }; u interface { main.f(); main.g() }; v interface { main.f(); main.g() }; w interface { main.f(); main.g() }; x interface { main.f(); main.g() }; y interface { main.f(); main.g() }; z interface { main.f(); main.g() } }
```

## Go 1 using [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), 65532

There is [a limit in package `reflect`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ed15e82413c7b16e21a493f5a647f68b46e965ee/src/reflect/type.go#L533) on the length of type names: `len(name) <= 1<<16-1`

I've been able to reach a type name of 65532 bytes so far with this block:

```
t:=reflect.TypeOf(0);u:=t;for i:=0;i<8191;i++{t=reflect.MapOf(u,t)};reflect.New(t).Interface()
```

[Full code on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gr7ayLr2M9P):

```
package main;import("fmt";"reflect")
func main() {

    t:=reflect.TypeOf(0);u:=t;for i:=0;i<8191;i++{t=reflect.MapOf(u,t)};x:=reflect.New(t).Interface()

    fmt.Printf("%d %T\n", len(fmt.Sprintf("%T", x)), x)
}
```

---

Notes: `x:=` is never counted.

Comment: invalid, `reflect` import would need to be counted

Comment: [3403?](https://tio.run/##TY7RCoIwFIbvfYoxEDY4Cd0mvkM07ypo2GZLN5fOUsRnt2MUdPEdDv/54Pxls3hZVLJUxErjImN90wZGtQ00pV1ojSs7yiPdu@JjME6mJYxeEZHhuS/C5OEBLXQQoIcnvGCA8UKMC6rVslCTZjwtkRtikDtSITViGZ/ndNhlVvqjOP9PMc0Ltkj2WCFoRuMrifOTo0Bq5di3WXJQvsYnbDWF/6k5WgMHQgkuFNlsOV@jaF7e)

Comment: [3685](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCsIwEEX3PUUIFBIYC24NvYPY7tRFqEmNNWlsU20JPXudiq5cvGH482B@3S5eVo2sFbHSuMRY33aBUW0DFbQPnXF1T3miB1d9DMZJXMLkFSlyPA9ViC14eEAHPQQY4AkvGGEixgXVaVmpqBkXNXJFDHJDGsbnWYy73Ep/LM7/s4jzIrBFtscKQTOaXkhanhwFcleOfZtlB@Xv@IOtZuF/aonWyIFQggtFNlvO1yiZlzc)

Comment: [65535](https://tio.run/##RY3RCoIwGIXv9xRjIGwoaoRduHyAbkrIy27G@icjnWP8kSE@u2kQ3RwO5/vgtMPilX6oFmivrCO290NAnrIApgONLGGmRyYkMU@nvw4XdFqybPP@GsGyat4eLobnQpohUFtWubTHQ1Hsd9LG8YRVjaEZOIpZjmV1htda05NDCEZp4GJZn9I6WIeGs@hOo@bmWEI7cHwjV/9DzbqOQmxB5uUD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 99 bytes, score=46,137,336

```rust
fn b<T>(a:T)->Result<T,T>{Ok(a)}b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(b(0))))))))))))))))))))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZLfToMwFMYT7-QpKhdLm7FF3c3Skb7ATExM423DsGw4KKQ9aCbhEXwCb3ahD6VPY8fAMLZknl7A-cP361f68akLA9ufi3fQQQyIb3J5J9USVqh0kI1IoaUEkdQ1TNCIocLEb3LmVI4Tp3nic9r5ypt3M9bVizKNHqQpEvC5N2dn9FE5RUPEKT3oDtH8sFK12-iT4sntOUDd3oWWUGiFJrO6Up12duRlwM9a6BOO7dx0mFYn17ECARYksqjHxyIGmVLLJVb5sh5N1BV2y8r1-tJjyIQBO7LEpCaMAyMWG5CmzXW4KtTa4Emby5e2lQY5NvBEqVWgNNJZKgqIpk03zJJEhkCp3_zNRxn6AzvKPCQYa0UK9aqtTpM9Z7HCrucSMmuspoGtkOaMDnzjQflleaPpd2jnFj5nOKCcjNjf7eGsvF_jgFQL_P91TU7GHvVV7Ta2f99u989f)

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 100 bytes, Score \$\approx 2.22128\times 10^{78}\$

The score is \$8+\underbrace{6\times(6\times(\cdots(6\times2+7)\cdots)+7)+7}_{100 \text{ levels}}=\$ `2221283319900241080728746908337396589826288615608046563246444685656290281023085`.

The type is `Option<((...(u8,u8,u8,u8,u8,u8),...))>`, with 100 levels of nested tuples, where each tuple contains 6 identical items.

```rust
type A<T>=(T,T,T,T,T,T);type B<T>=A<A<A<A<A<T>>>>>;type C<T>=B<B<B<B<B<T>>>>>;None::<C<C<C<C<u8>>>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 100 bytes, score = \$3.7996944224×10^{21}\$

```cs
class X<A,B,C,D,E,F,G>{class Y:X<Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y>{Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y.Y y;}}
```

---

Solution inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69200/113454).

There are two variables that contribute to the length of the type signature of the variable `y`: the number of generic type arguments on `X` and the number of nested class accesses in `Y`.

The following formula represents the length of the generated type signature not counting whitespace:

\$ L\ =\ \frac{x^{y}\cdot((x-1)(2x^{2}+5x+4)+x+4)-(x+4)}{(x-1)} \$

where `x` is the number of generic type arguments on `X` (e.g. for `X<A,B,C,D>`, `x = 4`) and `y` is the number of `.Y`s

Using Desmos and trial and error, I found the maximum length value where `x` and `y` would fit in 100 bytes was at `x=7` `y=23`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/OSexuFghwsZRx0nHWcdFx1XHTcfdrhoiHGkVYROpgwTtqiP1SIIKlda1tf//AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ceylon, 38843546786070481 (~ 4·10<sup>16</sup>)

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

This are 49 nested one-tuples, with an empty tuple innermost.
The short name of this type is actually the same as the value in this case, but the fully expanded name is much longer.

The Ceylon compiler is working forever when trying to compile this (The compiler was still running after 180 minutes) – I'll have to try calculating the theoretical type length.

The problem here is that a one-element-tuple type `[X]` is actually represented in Ceylon's type system as `Tuple<X, X, []>` (first parameter is a supertype for all element types, second is the type of the first element, and third the type of all except the first elements, which is here an empty tuple (the `empty` object, the single instance satisfying the interface `Empty`)).

So `[]` is `empty`, `[[]]` is `Tuple<[], [], []>` = `Tuple<empty, empty, empty>`, `[[[]]]` is `Tuple<[[]], [[]], []>` = `Tuple<Tuple<[], [], []>, Tuple<[], [], []>, []>`. And the full name includes the package names, so we have actually `ceylon.language::Tuple<ceylon.language::Tuple<ceylon.language::empty, ceylon.language::empty, ceylon.language::empty>, ceylon.language::Tuple<ceylon.language::empty, ceylon.language::empty, ceylon.language::empty>, ceylon.language::empty>` just for three levels. And we want to go to 50.

As `ceylon.language::empty` is 22 characters long, and each `ceylon.language::Tuple<?,?,ceylon.language::empty>` adds 47 to twice the result from the previous step, we get `f(1) = 22`, and `f(n) = 2 · f(n-1) + 47`. This simplifies to `f(n) = 69 · 2^(n - 1) - 47`, and entering 50 gives us 38843546786070481. Of course, this is much larger than what would fit in the memory of my computer (8·10<sup>9</sup> bytes).

Of course, the compiler could be smart and not try to have the whole type name in memory until its name is requested.

Here is the full program trying to print the type:

```ceylon
import ceylon.language.meta {
    type
}
"Run the module `codegolf.signature71797`."
shared void run() {
    value x = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]];
    print(type(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 99 bytes, Score 841

```cs
(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,(1,1,1))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F@WWKSQbqvxX8NQhyoICDVxgP@aeu6pJSGVBakamtZc4UWZJak@mXmpGumoPL2Q/OCSosy8dA1NPZ/UvPSSDAVtBSWF5IzEomKFnPy8dCVN6/8A)

Outputs

```cs
System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`2[System.Int32,System.ValueTuple`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Nice one! Adding one `m` after a 1 would make the byte count reach 100 and the score 843 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F@WWKSQbqvxX8MwV0fDkAoICDVxgP@aeu6pJSGVBakamtZc4UWZJak@mXmpGumoPL2Q/OCSosy8dA1NPZ/UvPSSDAVtBSWF5IzEomKFnPy8dCVN6/8A "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 782

Expression:

```
sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum.sum
```

Type signature:

```
:: (Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[[c]]]]]]], Num [[[[[[c]]]]]], Num [[[[[c]]]]], Num [[[[c]]]], Num [[[c]]], Num [[c]], Num [c], Num c) => [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[c]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] -> c
```

Comment: Becomes 1814 characters with ghc 8.0.2, as the type of `sum` then is `(Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a`