# Min-Max GHC command line error bytes to bytes of source code

Tags: code-challenge, haskell

GHC command line errors can be horrible, lets make them as bad as possible. To disincentivize very long programs use the following formula to calculate your "score".

```
(# of bytes of GHC output) / 2^(8 + # of bytes of code)
```

Template Haskell is banned as there is probably a TH configuration where you can replicate an error f(n) times where f is an arbitrary fast growing computable function. CPP and GHC options are banned for similar reasons.

GHC output should be computed using this release of [GHC 8.6.3](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_6_3.html).

To calculate the bytes of GHC output run:

```
ghc -hide-all-packages -package base Main.hs |& wc -c
```

The following is an example submission:

```
main = print (1 + True)
```

Error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:1:15: error:
    • No instance for (Num Bool) arising from a use of ‘+’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(1 + True)’
      In the expression: print (1 + True)
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (1 + True)
  |
1 | main = print (1 + True)
  |               ^^^^^^^^
```

Score:

```
375 / 2^(8 + 24) = 0.0000000873114914
```

Submissions must contain the code and the score. Highest score wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71797/71256). I suspect an answer inspired from there could be quite competitive. And probably (I'm pretty confident) could have an unbounded score

Comment: [yep](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81Ww0pTD4i50m3T9MCQKzcxM8/WUDtdL/3/fwA)

Comment: [2.9MB already](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMHGRj01L0VdwU7BNzEzTy@jmCvNVsNKUw@IudJt0/TAkCsXKGdrqJ2ul84FVM2VnpGsoJuRmZKqm5iTo1uQmJydmJ5arABjKSQlFqfCzFOoUVMoBypP/v8fAA)

Comment: I recommend looking into [tag:busy-beaver] challenges.  In particular, for these kinds of challenges, I often recommend a maximum length, and a requirement that the program must eventually halt.

Comment: @ASCII-only Your program’s score of 2919209/2^(8 + 30) ≈ 0.0000106 is handily beaten by the empty program’s score of 142/2^(8 + 0) = 0.5546875. However, the winning constructions at [Make a long type signature](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71797/71256) are doubly-exponential, so you can get an unbounded score. I don’t think this scoring system is going to work.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Yeah, definitely. Even that challenge has a length limit because of the same issue. Alternatively, maybe you could count type names as one byte long

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I was trying to solve the sensitivity around 0 with the plus 8. Do you have a better scoring method?

Comment: The plus 8 doesn’t do anything except uniformly divide all scores by 256. I think it’s going to be hard to find something that isn’t totally arbitrary and doesn’t strongly favor either the empty program or programs compiling with too many errors to fit in the visible universe. Maybe the challenge should be to find the shortest program that produces at least (say) 1000000 bytes of errors?

Comment: Also with that formulation, there’s probably no need to ban specific features like Template Haskell because it probably costs more bytes to use them than the shortest program to produce 1000000 bytes of errors. In fact, you could open the challenge up to any language with a concept of compile errors, not just Haskell.

Comment: @ASCII-only This is beautiful! :)

Comment: @flawr I stole it off the linked question though

Answer (score 4):

## Score diverges to \$\infty\$

```haskell
f=(:).(:)
g=f.f.f.f.f.f.f.f -- adding ".f" always results in better score
main=g+main g
```

Based on ASCII-only's construction, it is pretty easy to get ever-increasing score with longer and longer programs. Just posting to knock the challenge out of the unanswered list.

Given the following program form

```haskell
f=(:).(:).(:) -- n copies of (:) composed
main=f+main f
```

the sizes of error messages are:

```
2 copies -> 2328
3 copies -> 8121 (x3.488)
4 copies -> 27121 (x3.339)
5 copies -> 103385 (x3.812)
6 copies -> 432486 (x4.183)
7 copies -> 1898125 (x4.388)
8 copies -> 8495224 (x4.475)
9 copies -> 39395094 (x4.637)
10 copies -> 198171503 (x5.030)
```

We can't know the exact formula of this because Haskell's error message pretty-printing is complicated, but we can at least know that adding one copy of `.(:)` consistently increases the error size by a factor of 4 or higher. In the top submission, adding two characters `.f` adds two copies of `(:)`, multiplying the error size by at least 16 and therefore the score by
\$16 \div 4 = 4\$.

To roughly see what is going on, here's the full error for 1-copy `(:)` program: (those `��`s are pretty quotes, which got somehow broken in my editor)

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:2:1: error:
    ? Couldn't match expected type ��IO t0��
                  with actual type ��(a0 -> [a0] -> [a0])
                                    -> (a0 -> [a0] -> [a0])
                                    -> [a0 -> [a0] -> [a0]]
                                    -> [a0 -> [a0] -> [a0]]��
    ? Probable cause: ��main�� is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action ��main��
  |
2 | main=f+main f
  | ^

Main.hs:2:6: error:
    ? Couldn't match type ��[a -> [a] -> [a]]�� with ��a -> [a] -> [a]��
      Expected type: (a -> [a] -> [a])
                     -> (a -> [a] -> [a]) -> [a -> [a] -> [a]] -> [a -> [a] -> [a]]
        Actual type: (a -> [a] -> [a])
                     -> [a -> [a] -> [a]] -> [a -> [a] -> [a]]
    ? Possible cause: ��(+)�� is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: f + main f
      In an equation for ��main��: main = f + main f
    ? Relevant bindings include
        main :: (a -> [a] -> [a])
                -> (a -> [a] -> [a]) -> [a -> [a] -> [a]] -> [a -> [a] -> [a]]
          (bound at Main.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | main=f+main f
  |      ^^^^^^^^
```

and for 2-copy `(:)` program:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:2:1: error:
    ? Couldn't match expected type ��IO t0��
                  with actual type ��(a0 -> [[a0] -> [a0]] -> [[a0] -> [a0]])
                                    -> (a0 -> [[a0] -> [a0]] -> [[a0] -> [a0]])
                                    -> [[a0 -> [[a0] -> [a0]] -> [[a0] -> [a0]]]
                                        -> [a0 -> [[a0] -> [a0]] -> [[a0] -> [a0]]]]
                                    -> [[a0 -> [[a0] -> [a0]] -> [[a0] -> [a0]]]
                                        -> [a0 -> [[a0] -> [a0]] -> [[a0] -> [a0]]]]��
    ? Probable cause: ��main�� is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action ��main��
  |
2 | main=f+main f
  | ^

Main.hs:2:6: error:
    ? Couldn't match type ��[[a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
                            -> [a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]]��
                     with ��a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]��
      Expected type: (a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]])
                     -> (a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]])
                     -> [[a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
                         -> [a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]]
                     -> [[a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
                         -> [a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]]
        Actual type: (a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]])
                     -> [[a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
                         -> [a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]]
                     -> [[a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
                         -> [a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]]
    ? Possible cause: ��(+)�� is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: f + main f
      In an equation for ��main��: main = f + main f
    ? Relevant bindings include
        main :: (a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]])
                -> (a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]])
                -> [[a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
                    -> [a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]]
                -> [[a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]
                    -> [a -> [[a] -> [a]] -> [[a] -> [a]]]]
          (bound at Main.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | main=f+main f
  |      ^^^^^^^^
```

Basically the inferred type signature of `main` is blowing up by factor of >4. The type has the format of `x -> y -> z -> w`, where each of `x, y, z, w` contains the sub-structure `p -> q -> r`. When a copy of `(:)` is added, `q` and `r` parts are doubled and `z` and `w` are quadrupled.