# Build a Markdown bomb

Tags: code-challenge, busy-beaver

I'm sure most of us have heard of [zip bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb) and similar decompression bomb tricks, where a maliciously crafted input creates a massively disproportionate output.  We even had [a question on here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69189/build-a-compiler-bomb) to do that to a compiler at one point.

Well, it occurs to me that Markdown is a compression format of sorts, replacing bulky HTML tags with "compressed" MD tokens.  Therefore, might it be possible to build a compression bomb in Markdown?

## Challenge rules:

- The submission should be a piece of markdown text, between 50 and 256 characters in length.  (Imposing a minimum to head off some smart-aleck posting a 3-character response or similar.)
- The submission will be processed by StackExchange's Markdown processor as implemented in this site.
- Your score will be the ratio of character count in the resulting HTML to the character count of your Markdown text.
- Highest score wins.

Comment: The [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/286319) may come in handy for people to test before they post an answer.

Comment: We might need a standard interpreter / viewer / checker system. People are getting different byte counts for the same code because some tags are / are not showing up.

Comment: This is going to devolve into mathjax/latex actual busy beaver code

Comment: @isaacg: I'll be impressed if you can come up with something that's worse than linear after trimming indentation.

Comment: @Joshua See this answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172523/20080

Comment: Should Mathjax actually be allowed? It's not Markdown.

Comment: Should we count the *rendered* HTML or the *source* HTML? Language highlighting and MathJax are done client-side, not server-side.

Comment: **Warning**: Testing some large answers to this challenge may exhaust your RAM.

Comment: @curiousdannii I did say "the markdown interpreter *as implemented in this site.*"  Some SE sites have MathJax support, but I think this isn't one of them, and I've noticed that none of the MathJax examples actually show the rendered output.

Comment: @MasonWheeler [This list says this site does support Mathjax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/256282). But it still doesn't make sense to me for mathjax to be considered markdown just because it can be combined with it. Edit: now I see below that you also don't think it counts. So cool :)

Comment: The "rendered or source" issue and whether MathJax is allowed **really** needs to be clarified. You can't just say "ok this is probably invalid but nice".

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Unfortunately, StackExchange markup rendering is not a consistent interpreter, as it will change over time, and there will be no way to verify old answers once it does, because you cannot link to an old "interpreter".

Comment: @Timtech It's weird that OP accepts the highest voted instead of the highest score answer, but "score" != "votes tally". Not a pop-con.

Comment: @MasonWheeler You should fix this some way soon or it will be closed. It has 4 close votes already.

Comment: @user202729 My bad, looking back I don't know how I got the impression that this was a popularity contest.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

## Blockquotes, 137,469/256 = 536.99

*6,908 characters, 511 new lines, 130,050 spaces*

Markdown sure handles nested block-quotes oddly.  Each `>` character gets turned into `<blockquote></blockquote>` so a solid 1 to 25 ratio. But wait! When rendering the HTML it also adds two spaces per nesting! Having this try to render causes my browser some grief, and I will keep it in the code-cage for now. Feel free to unlock it yourself!

The code input consists of 255 `>` followed by <s>`&` as the last character doesn't transform, but it does get escaped. *Thanks BWO*</s> `!` as the last character which gives the last blockquote the spoiler class with an empty p tag inside. *Thanks bta, 11 extra characters*

Input:
`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>!`

Output HTML:

```
...
  <blockquote>
    <blockquote class="spoiler">
      <p></p>
    </blockquote>
  </blockquote>
...
```

Here is what it looks like in the editor view!
[image: crazy nested block quotes, makes a big triangle pointing right!]

Plotting the results as the number of `>` increase as suggested by LambdaBeta:
[image]

Comment: Try plotting the results as you increase the '>' count. I wonder if the renderer will also add the formatting spaces...

Comment: The funny thing here is, that the blockquotes nicely overflow the article column at least in the editing preview.

Comment: If you add `!` before the ampersand, then the last level of blockquote will get ` class="spoiler"` added to it.  Add it to any other level and it *shortens* the output, though.

Comment: removing one greater than sign loses 1k characters! :0

Comment: I'm so ashamed I didn't think of this

Comment: @SvenWritesCode - True.  You can also replace the trailing `&` with `!` to get the same effect.

Comment: Now this is "arrow code" if I've ever seen it.

Comment: Nice. This is quadratic growth because the j-th quote adds O(j) new characters, so we get big-O of 1+2+...+n = O(n^2). You can see this from the picture where the triangle's height is the number of quotes n and its width is O(n), so its area is O(n^2). The other non-Mathjax answers seem to be only linear growth (the billion-laughts MathJax one is exponential).

Comment: @usul The shorthand links answer is also quadratic growth; the length of the URL is multiplied by the number of references to it.

Answer (score 63):

## MathJax, 529\$\,\$252\$\,\$640<sub>ish</sub> / 256 ≈ 2\$\,\$067\$\,\$393

A good old thousand-laughs-style code

`$$\def\a{}\def\b{\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a}\def\c{\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b}\def\d{\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c}\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$$`

multiplies the gross inefficiency of representing exotic characters in MathJax by a considerable factor.

The StackExchange MathJax configuration limitation of 10\$\,\$000 macro expansions is being honored, while the limitations of the client’s browser, which are highly likely to cause problems expanding the macros, are not. (My browser is uncooperative as well, so the figure is an estimate.)

Comment: For anyone else wondering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack

Comment: See also: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/43

Comment: @user202729 my code causes something like 8865 macro expansions, out of 10000 permitted by MathJax as configured on StackExchange. If not for that restriction, less tildes and more nesting levels would produce way more output.

Comment: This is a cool find, but it's not Markdown and MathJax is not supported on this site, so it's kind of outside the stated parameters of the rules.

Comment: \$are^{you^{sure}}\$ it’s not supported? The page titled “**Markdown** Editing Help” at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help explicitly mentions LaTeX.

Comment: It would be a nice exercise to see what ratio of definition lengths would yield the longest result. How many `~` in `\a`, how many `\a` in `\b`, and so on (and whether to stop at `\d`, or keep going).

Comment: @Arthur do you think the numbers chosen are random? :−)

Comment: @RomanOdaisky Not at all. You've probably done the calculation yourself, and reached this conclusion. I'm just saying, as a math teacher and enthusiast, that it seems like it would be a cool exercise.

Comment: Hmm. It's easy to make *much* larger expansion in (La)TeX proper, but all fun seems to be disallowed in MathJax: count registers, conditionals, \expandafter, even \edef.

Comment: @RomanOdaisky if you embed a simplified version of the code in your post to demonstrate that the theory works in the specified environment (i.e. "here"), I suspect the debate of "whether or not it's supported" will be a bit easier to resolve.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Your wish is my command \$\def\a{}\def\b{\a\a}\def\c{\b\b}\def\d{\c\c}\d\d\$

Answer (score 26):

## Shorthand links: 68,960 / 256 = 269.375

ASCII only: 10,114 / 256 = 39.508

```
[][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1][][1]
[1]:ftp://^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Output is a sequence of elements that each look like:

```
<a href="ftp://%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E" rel="nofollow noreferrer"></a>
```

After the fixed overhead for creating the URL reference, each 5-character link expands into `42+strlen(url)` characters output.  Craft the URL to have the maximum number of characters that need escaping, and this grows to `47+3*strlen(url)` characters per link.  A little experimentation showed that the optimal output involved 26 links, with 114 carets per link.

**Update**:
If you interpret the "256 character" limit to include Unicode characters, you can squeeze out more chaos.  Replacing the carets with the Unicode bathtub character (, codepoint U+1F6C1) results in `47+18*strlen(url)` output characters per input character for a total of <strike>54,574</strike> 68,960 (thanks to jimmy23013's even-shorter link notation).

Unicode input:

```
[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]
[1]:ftp://
```

Output is a series of:

```
<a href="ftp://%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD...per character...%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD" rel="nofollow noreferrer">1</a>,
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a very clever answer!

Comment: 1. You can use `[1],[1],[1]...` for the links. 2. `&quot;` has more characters than `%5E` in the non-Unicode version.

Answer (score 15):

## 15888/50 = 317.76: Abuse of MathJaX

This is the code:

```
$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$
```

This is what it looks like:

$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$$$&$$

The resulting HTML is:

```
<p><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-618-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3081" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3082"><span id="MathJax-Span-3083" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3084"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3085" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-618">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-619-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3086" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3087"><span id="MathJax-Span-3088" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3089"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3090" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-619">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-620-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3091" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3092"><span id="MathJax-Span-3093" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3094"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3095" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-620">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-621-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3096" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3097"><span id="MathJax-Span-3098" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3099"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3100" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-621">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-622-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3101" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3102"><span id="MathJax-Span-3103" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3104"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3105" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-622">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-623-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3106" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3107"><span id="MathJax-Span-3108" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3109"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3110" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-623">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-624-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3111" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3112"><span id="MathJax-Span-3113" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3114"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3115" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-624">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-625-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3116" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3117"><span id="MathJax-Span-3118" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3119"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3120" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-625">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-626-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3121" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3122"><span id="MathJax-Span-3123" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3124"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3125" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-626">&</script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;"><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-627-Frame" tabindex="0" style="text-align: center; position: relative;" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; display=&quot;block&quot;><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;amp;</mtext></merror></math>" role="presentation"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-3126" style="width: 5.447em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.503em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.114em, 1004.5em, 2.614em, -999.997em); top: -2.164em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3127"><span id="MathJax-Span-3128" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="merror" id="null"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-3129"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-3130" style=""><span style="font-size: 83%;">Misplaced &amp;</span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.169em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.397em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.537em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><merror><mtext>Misplaced &amp;</mtext></merror></math></span></span></div><script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-627">&</script></p>
```

Don't forget your MathJax folks.

Caveat: The MathJaX only shows the error during editing, so you have to view it in the editor. This is still a markdown implementation on this site, so should be valid. Once posted the `Misplaced &` warnings turn into normal &'s.

Answer (score 14):

## Syntax highlighting, <s>6376</s> 6464/256 ≈ 25.25

<sup>+0.34375 thanks to [Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel?tab=profile) (using a tab instead of 4 spaces)!</sup>

This uses the shortest (unfortunately spaces seem to matter) annotation to get syntax-highlighting `lang-c`, opens a code block and fills it with `&` and `0`:

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

    &0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
```

We start with `&` because it expands to `&amp;` and use `0` next, alternating these constantly creates new `<span>` elements with a `class` attribute. Unfortunately we can't use only `&` or `&<&<...` since they stay in the same `pun`-`<div>`

It produces:

```
<pre class="lang-c prettyprint prettyprinted" style=""><code><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span><span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="lit">0</span></code></pre></div>
```

And rendered by your browser it results in:

```c
&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
```

Comment: If you look at the source code for this page, the HTML is just `<pre class="lang-c prettyprint-override"><code>&amp;0&amp;0&amp; ... 0&amp;0&amp;0&amp;
</code></pre>` where `...` is more of the same. The span tags aren't there at all. That's a score of 739/256 = 2.887

Comment: @EngineerToast: What browser? I'm using Firefox 62 and they show up, I noticed with another answer that I get another score, so I guess this depends on the browser..

Comment: Well... That's going to be a problem. I'll ask OP to standardize.

Comment: @EngineerToast That's caused by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172480/build-a-markdown-bomb#comment416171_172480).

Comment: Instead of 4 spaces, use a single tab. It works too!

Answer (score 5):

## 190/50 = 3.8: Italics

As it turns out, your 3-character worry is true. `*q*` generates `<em>q</em>` giving a ratio of 10/3. Two carriage returns give `<p>...</p>\n\n` (the two carriage returns aren't necessary, but do appear to be produced) and a resulting ratio of 9/2. Total ratio, 19/5.

```
*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*
```

Resulting html:

```
<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>

<p><em>q</em></p>
```

In action:

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

*q*

Comment: Using `> q` to use `<blockquote>` instead of `<em>` is better. (note: you do it to every other line, otherwise its just one tag)

Comment: @LambdaBeta I didn't even think about Blockquote. Yeah, [that one exploded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172493/47990).

Answer (score 5):

## 222/53 = <4.2: Nasty escapes in an image inclusion.

```
> ![&](https://&)

![&](https://&)
> ![&](https://&)
```

Results in:

> [image: &]

[image: &]

> [image: &]

Resulting HTML should be approximately:

```
<blockquote>
  <p><img src="https://&amp;" alt="&amp;" title=""></p>
</blockquote>

<p><img src="https://&amp;" alt="&amp;" title=""></p>

<blockquote>
  <p><img src="https://&amp;" alt="&amp;" title=""></p>
</blockquote>
```

This abuses image inclusion and having to escape things.

It used to be much better, but apparently SE's markdown is sufficiently non-standard to ruin it.

My previous submission (which wasn't how SE rendered it) was:

## <s>428/50 = 8.56: Nasty escapes in an image inclusion.</s>

`![&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&](&)`

Resulting HTML should be approximately:

```
<p><img src="&amp;" alt="&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;&amp;amp;"></p>
```

This abuses the fact that most markdown editors will replace the ampersands in the alt text with doubly-escaped ampersands in order for it to show up correctly. Meanwhile a single ampersand is tossed into the src section so that the parser will actually see it as an image.

Comment: Would _ε_ be translated to _&epsilon;_ or _&#949;_?

Comment: I don't know. As far as I can tell it doesn't actually work - debugging it a bit now. I used & because in theory for alt-text to show up correctly it has to be escaped twice (&amp;amp;). This works in most markdowns, but doesn't seem to produce any output at all in SE...

Comment: Couldn't you compress this with `[1]:https://&` on a line, and then use `![&][1]` more times?

Comment: Does it really have to be https? http would give you less unexpanded characters. Or ftp if that works.

Answer (score 4):

## MathJax: 13,579 / 52 = 261.13

```
\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$
```

Just creates a bunch of empty in-line MathJax:

\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$

HTML Code (can inspect on the empty space above):

```
<p><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1064-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2127" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2128"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1064"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1065-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2129" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2130"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1065"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1066-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2131" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2132"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1066"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1067-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2133" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2134"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1067"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1068-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2135" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2136"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1068"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1069-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2137" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2138"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1069"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1070-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2139" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2140"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1070"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1071-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2141" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2142"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1071"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1072-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2143" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2144"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1072"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1073-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2145" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2146"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1073"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1074-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2147" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2148"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1074"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1075-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2149" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2150"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1075"></script><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="display: none;"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-1076-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot; />" role="presentation" style="position: relative;"><nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2151" style="width: 0em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.785em, 1000em, 4.17em, -999.997em); top: -3.971em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2152"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.978em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.073em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 0.158em;"></span></span></nobr><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1076"></script></p>
```

Comment: You can get more with errors. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## 4830 / 256 = 18.87

```
[1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1<p>1](http://localhost:8080/welcome-to-my-fantastic-amazing-homepage-and-why-not-share-it-to-your-facebook-right-now.html)
```

An idea based on HTML autocorrect. Not quite high score though.

Answer (score 2):

## 421 / 56 = 7.518

```
>&

&
>&

&
>&

&
>&

&
>&

&
>&

&
>&
```

Which produces the following HTML on SE:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>&amp;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>&amp;</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&amp;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>&amp;</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&amp;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>&amp;</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&amp;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>&amp;</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&amp;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>&amp;</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&amp;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>&amp;</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&amp;</p>
</blockquote>
```

... and the following output:

---

> &

&

> &

&

> &

&

> &

&

> &

&

> &

&

> &

Answer (score 1):

## 11190 / 255 = ~43.88

I was inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172493/43446) top answer, but am too dumb to beat it and reached the max character count so, I guess I'll have to be satisfied with what I have ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. There's actually two spaces after the last blockquote, but the formatting does not show it.

`> - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - > - >`

**HTML:**

```
<blockquote>
  <ul>
  <li><blockquote>
    <ul><li><blockquote>
      <ul><li><blockquote>
        <ul><li><blockquote>
          <ul><li><blockquote>
            <ul><li><blockquote>
              <ul><li><blockquote>
                <ul><li><blockquote>
                  <ul><li><blockquote>
                    <ul><li><blockquote>
                      <ul><li><blockquote>
                        <ul><li><blockquote>
                          <ul><li><blockquote>
                            <ul><li><blockquote>
                              <ul><li><blockquote>
                                <ul><li><blockquote>
                                  <ul><li><blockquote>
                                    <ul><li><blockquote>
                                      <ul><li><blockquote>
                                        <ul><li><blockquote>
                                          <ul><li><blockquote>
                                            <ul><li><blockquote>
                                              <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                  <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                    <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                      <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                        <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                          <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                            <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                              <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                  <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                    <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                      <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                        <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                          <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                            <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                              <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                  <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                    <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                      <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                        <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                          <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                            <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                              <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                  <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                    <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                      <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                        <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                          <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                            <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                              <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                  <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                    <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                      <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                        <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                          <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                            <ul><li><blockquote>
                                                                                                                              <ul><li><blockquote>

                                                                                                                              </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                                            </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                                          </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                                        </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                                      </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                                    </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                                  </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                                </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                              </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                            </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                          </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                        </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                      </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                    </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                  </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                                </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                              </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                            </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                          </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                        </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                      </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                    </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                  </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                                </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                              </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                            </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                          </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                        </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                      </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                    </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                  </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                                </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                              </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                            </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                          </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                        </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                      </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                    </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                  </blockquote></li></ul>
                                                </blockquote></li></ul>
                                              </blockquote></li></ul>
                                            </blockquote></li></ul>
                                          </blockquote></li></ul>
                                        </blockquote></li></ul>
                                      </blockquote></li></ul>
                                    </blockquote></li></ul>
                                  </blockquote></li></ul>
                                </blockquote></li></ul>
                              </blockquote></li></ul>
                            </blockquote></li></ul>
                          </blockquote></li></ul>
                        </blockquote></li></ul>
                      </blockquote></li></ul>
                    </blockquote></li></ul>
                  </blockquote></li></ul>
                </blockquote></li></ul>
              </blockquote></li></ul>
            </blockquote></li></ul>
          </blockquote></li></ul>
        </blockquote></li></ul>
      </blockquote></li></ul>
    </blockquote></li></ul>
  </blockquote></li>
  </ul>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: the code itself looks like a blockquote